# Docker Async limitation Python

Tags: python, docker, flask, python-asyncio

I have a flask code that pings an API using Python Async and Meilisearch. The code runs well locally, however when I deploy it on the company server using Docker, it crashes when the task takes too long.
Here are the relevant files:
views.py

```
from app import app
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_file, send_from_directory, flash
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import os
import pandas as pd
from app.static.standardize import cleanup
from app.static.search_meili import *

@app.route('/')
def home():
   return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/upload')
def upload_file():
   return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def uploader_file():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']
      f.save(f.filename)
      uploads = os.getcwd() + '/uploads/'
      os.rename(f.filename, uploads + f.filename)
      if f.filename.endswith('.csv'):
          df = pd.read_csv(uploads + f.filename)
          output = f.filename[:-4] + '_out.csv'
      elif f.filename.endswith('xlsx'):
          df = pd.read_excel(uploads + f.filename)
          output = f.filename[:-5] + '_out.xlsx'

      if 'standardized_names' in df.columns.str.strip().str.lower():
          pass
      else:
          df['NAMES'] = df['NAMES'].astype(str)
          df['NAMES'] = df['NAMES'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('+-='))
          df['standardized_names'] = cleanup(df)
      loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
      loop.run_until_complete(run_search(df))
      df.to_excel(output)
      output_dir = os.getcwd() + '/output_files/'
      os.rename(output,  output_dir + output)
      return send_from_directory(output_dir, output, as_attachment=True)
```

This will runs a function run_search from the search_meili file:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz
import pandas as pd
import asyncio
from meilisearch_python_async.errors import MeilisearchError
from meilisearch_python_async import Client
import sys
semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(50)
async def search_Meili(df, q: str):
    async with semaphore:
        async with Client("COMPANY SERVER") as client:

            index = client.index("GK")
            try:
                search_result = await index.search(q, limit=1)
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            except MeilisearchError as E:
                name = ''
                score = 0
                matched_gk = 0
                nb_hits = 0
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
                return df.loc[df["standardized_names"] == q,
                    ["hits", "matched_gk", 'matched_name', 'score']] == [nb_hits, matched_gk, name, score]
            nb_hits = search_result.estimated_total_hits
            if nb_hits != 0:
                alt_names = []
                #Return the best result only
                best_result = search_result.hits[0]
                name = best_result.get('name')
                matched_gk = best_result.get('GK')
                if len(best_result.get('Alt_Names')) == 0:
                    score = fuzz.ratio(name , q)
                else:
                    alt_names = best_result.get('Alt_Names')
                    alt_names.append(name)
                    name , score = process.extractOne(q, alt_names)
            else:
                name = ''
                score = 0
                matched_gk = 0
                nb_hits = 0
            df.loc[df["standardized_names"] == q,
                ["hits", "matched_gk", 'matched_name', 'score']] = [[nb_hits, matched_gk, name, score]]

async def run_search(df):
    await asyncio.gather(*[search_Meili(df, q) for q in df["standardized_names"]])
```

Then I use this Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
ENV http_proxy "COMPANY SERVER"
ENV https_proxy "COMPANY SERVERR"

COPY ./requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["./gunicorn.sh"]
```

And the gunicorn file:

```
#!/bin/sh
gunicorn --chdir app app:app -w 2 --threads 2 --timeout 120 -b 0.0.0.0:80
```

I'm getting timeout errors w.r.t event loops like
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'.

Or at 504 Gateway Time-out.
My guess is that theres something going on with Docker/my companys server that is causing these issues but I'm not entirely sure.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace you can share?

Comment: For context I am trying to see if the error is coming from `meilisearch-python-async` (I am the creator of this package) and if so I want to try to find a way to fix it. I've tried to recreate the error, but so far haven't been able to.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was working on this code at a previous company and don't have access to it anymore. If it makes you feel any better I'm fairly confident that Meilisearch was not the issue but most likely due to a request taking too long. Cheers